# create an hotspot and set an image without background (like earth icon) to my panel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jvm-hotspot

I try to create  a  hotspot  by Extends of canvas and I try to add it on a panel which is  painted by images. So I must draw an icon (image) instead of clear rectangle of the screen. To do that I override the paint method to draw the icon I want to use. So far there is no problem; the hotspot works correctly and the icon is painted in the true size I want (32 x 24 pixels).

I try to add this hotspot after painting an image on the my panel in `mypanel.paint(g)` that override too.

The problem is that I use a car icon  that has  no background! (I hope you can understand me) Just the car icon must be shown on the panel that is painted with my images.
But an unwanted rectangle is created around the icon and makes a bad view.
How I can paint my icon  on the panel without that background?
Please help me.

Comment: A screenshot would help.

Comment: You talked about "an unwanted rectangle create around the icon". Can you send a picture of this, to know what is it exactly? A [screenshot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screenshot) is a capture from your screen, to save as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem solve by using JLable component, i extends JLabeles and set an icon to it, then i add a mouse listener to get mouse clicked event and then set Hand curser to it,
so the hotspot as a true HotSpot !!